# HTML5 video not working in Opera and Firefox

Tags: css, html, video

I've put a few HTML5 videos on my website and just noticed that they don't play in Opera and Firefox, but work fine in Chrome and Safari. They're 720p videos but I scaled the player down proportionally because a full 720p won't fit in my layout (not sure if that's an issue).

Here's an example of a video on my site, although the same thing happens with all my video pages: http://willryan.us/video_tilda.html

Comment: How is this offtopic???? It's the first thing google returns for "html5 video not working in opera", and you say it's offtopic? How about your rather save time for developers by upgrading the question. What's the point of closing all the issues as offtopic, not a real question, etc. When the google brings me here, it means it IS A REAL QUESTION and it IS ON TOPIC, dammit!1!

Comment: For anyone searching how to use `<video>` for all browsers, this should work: `<video><source src="video.webm" type="video/webm"><source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4"><!--required by ie+ios--></video>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different browsers support different video formats. Currently, there are three formats you you should use to encode your videos:

- MP4 (H.264 video + AAC audio) [proprietary, best video-quality],
- WebM (VP8 video + Ogg Vorbis audio) [open, H.264-comparable video-quality],
- Ogg Theora [open, lower video-quality compared with MP4/H.264 and WebM].

Your page contain MP4 variant only. For more compatibility with different browsers, you should additionally provide at least WebM variant.

You can try to use free tools like [XviD4PSP](http://www.winnydows.com/html5/) to transcode your videos to different formats.

Comment: Ahhh so it works similarly to using different font formats when using @font-face. I always assumed mp4 was all you needed. Is there an easy way to convert to the other necessary formats?

Comment: I've added transcode-tool example to my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found this converter: http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/ that I'm playing around with. It seems very straightforward, I'm hoping it's only converting without mucking with the resolution/compression...

Answer (score 1):

It could be in another format other than standard webm format which Firefox supports. You can try to [install the non standard support in Firefox.](http://www.interoperabilitybridges.com/html5-extension-for-wmp-plugin)